# Naming a "do X if needed" method

Tags: language-agnostic, naming, coding-standards

What is a good way to name a method that checks if X needs to be done, and does X it if necessary?

For example, how to name a method that updates a user list if new users have logged in? `UpdateListIfNeeded` seems too long, while simple `UpdateList` implies a possibly expensive and unnecessary operation is done every time. `EnsureListUpdated` is a variant as well.

C# has a `bool TryXXX(args, out result)` pattern (e.g. `int.TryParse(str, out num)`) to check if X is **possible** and do it, but that is subtly different.

Comment: Just a point of recommendation, methods like this, while well intentioned, should be created with caution.  Along the way they tend to get peppered into unrelated code under the guise of "just in case" or "adding a call to it in X() fixed a bug, but I'm not sure why".  If you have the discipline to only call `RefreshUserList()` during `LoginUser()` and `LogoutUser()`, and not during, say `GetUser()` (where the list should be up-to-date already), then by all means the advice below applies.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160261/929164

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I tend to use `Ensure`.  It carries the meaning of making sure that something is taken care of, however that needs to be done.  If it's already fine, just check it and we're done.  Otherwise, do it.  Either way, just *ensure that it gets done*.

Comment: i like this answer, in fact my code is full of `updateCounterIfNeeded` methods, `ensureCounterIsUpdated` sounds much much better. I will propose to stick to this convention to my team.

Answer (score 16):

My preference is `UpdateList`.  If nothing needs to be done, so be it.  The expense should always be minimized anyway, so if `UpdateList` is doing more than necessary something is incorrect in its implementation.

Basically it's the verb that tells you what the method should do.  `CalculateX` should always recalculate X.  `GetY` should always return Y, but only do the work of retrieving it if necessary.  Likewise, `UpdateZ` requests an update of Z assuming it's done the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 3):

### Call me "Maybe"

Co-opted from Haskell snippets I've seen, try

```
UpdateListMaybe();
```

Comment: I suppose if I understood Haskell better, this might make more sense.  Corollary: If this is used in a language other than Haskell, it will only be understood by those who know Haskell.

Comment: Six years later, I am a different programmer, with slightly more knowledge of Haskell things. I no longer endorse this answer, haha. I guess my idea at the time was to use the word "maybe" to signify that the function handles some sort of optionality. I still do that sometimes (e.g. Option[A] => B is called maybeToB)